# how to configure opendkim on ubuntu 14.04 mail server ( Postfix – dovecot )

Tags: 14.04, server, email, postfix, mail

I can't config DKIM on my server (Ubuntu 14.04).
Is there any tutorial to it?
(My mail server has been configured according to this manual : http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 1):

First install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install opendkim opendkim-tools
```

Add the following to `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
Domain    example.com
KeyFile    /etc/postfix/dkim.key
Selector    dkim
SOCKET    inet:8891@localhost
```

Add the following to `/etc/default/opendkim`:

```
SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"
```

Append a suitable DKIM configuration to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

You must append `no_milters` to the `receive_override_options` line in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`. This prevents multiple signatures being placed on the same outgoing mail item

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
```

Now you can generate a private key for signing outgoing mail. Note that in the following command, `dkim` is the value given to Selector in `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

```
opendkim-genkey -t -s dkim -d example.com
```

Move the key into place, but don't forget to take a copy and keep that copy backed up somewhere safe:

```
mv dkim.private /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

You'll need to restart Postfix and OpenDKIM services to pick up the configuration changes so that outgoing mail is signed using DKIM:

```
service opendkim start
service postfix restart
```

Next up is the DNS record setup. How you do this is again completely dependent on how you manage DNS or how it is managed for you - everyone's tools are different.

The file `dkim.txt` contains the following content, the full TXT record that must be created. It has the subdomain `dkim._domainkey` and a long set of encoded content as the value. Again "dkim" is the value given to Selector in `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

```
dkim._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=y; "
"p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC9rulKo58JIb5h+3MMEnYhlnbuVgRoA4w68R/X7qA2Lfv3RpdrrUb+r7KxemIo6PUIOm6uZ5OymhBgpJ0LAWBHBSJjnFmDXNajSgxMOcvkpgmVCW1/k1kxK864WVVSyFVQPyUImqklY+ws4u+mog3PSbuq2J8NFAnvSwzMg3vT1QIDAQAB" ; ----- DKIM key mail for example.com
```

When setting this up you should omit the `k=rsa; t=y;` portion of the value. The first item there refers to the key format and that defaults to RSA. They second denotes that this is a test entry, and should not be included. So the value looks like this:

```
"v=DKIM1; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC9rulKo58JIb5h+3MMEnYhlnbuVgRoA4w68R/X7qA2Lfv3RpdrrUb+r7KxemIo6PUIOm6uZ5OymhBgpJ0LAWBHBSJjnFmDXNajSgxMOcvkpgmVCW1/k1kxK864WVVSyFVQPyUImqklY+ws4u+mog3PSbuq2J8NFAnvSwzMg3vT1QIDAQAB"
```

It is helpful to view examples in the wild for the purposes of comparison, so that you can see how you should enter the value into your records. You can use the [DKIM key checker](https://protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/) or other tools such as dig. Note that the `dkim._domainkey` is the subdomain in the following command:

```
dig dkim._domainkey.twitter.com txt
```

EDIT 1

Change in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` form

```
# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

to

```
smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol         = 2
```

Restart `postfix`. Check status for service `opendkim` and `postfix`. Check mail singing again.

Comment: What is the difference between inet:127.0.0.1:8891 and inet:localhost:8891 ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 = localhost there is no difference. Difference between code is in line `non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891` witch is wrong and `non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters` witch is right.

Comment: Thanks, @2707974. But why is wrong?